# Un familiar error in asp.net when an event click..Failed to Load View State

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

Server Error in '/DIY' Application.
Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

Can anyone please advice me w/ this error I'm using asp.net.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1295517.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when javascript is modifying server-side HTML controls (runat="server") on the page prior to postback.

For example, if you're modifying an asp:DropDownList's items via javascript.

If you post the code of the page having issues, you may get more specific answers.